# How to pass perameters with third party url?

Tags: wordpress

[Check this image first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwRZW.png)

In the picture above you can see that there are 4 buttons with four different plans and all buttons linked with the third party link (Something Like https://example.com/) so I want that if the user is checking or click on the second plan button then URL should be like https://example.com?2 so we know that which plan user is checking. Any idea about this. Is it possible to pass parameters or whatever to the third-party link? I am using wordpress.

Comment: Is button directly link with third party url?

Comment: You can set the query paramters to the third party url  from where the code is executed.